# How to get oauth token using certificate based authentication in a karate script?

Tags: karate

We are using a jks file to to fetch an oauth2 token , its working perfectly fine when we use it in the application.yml (by setting these values -`Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=xyz-test.jks` and `-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=pass`)
but getting this error when tried in the feature file:

> Received invalid OAuth client credentials request.

The jks file has PrivateKeyEntry(xyz-qa) and trustedCertEntry (xyz-qa)

Below is our feature file

```
Feature: 
  Background:
    * url 'https://abcd.com'
    * configure ssl = { keyStore: 'classpath:xyz.jks', keyStorePassword: 'pass', keyStoreType: 'pkcs12' }

    Given path '/oauth2/token'
    And form field grant_type = 'client_credentials'
    And form field client_id = 'O767679'
    And form field key_alias = 'xyz-qa'
    And form field certificate_alias = 'xyz-qa-pub'
    And form field resource = 'resource'
    And method post
    Then status 200
```

Please help, let me know if any more information is required.

Expecting an access token but getting error message:

> {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"MSIS9627: Received invalid OAuth client credentials request. Client credentials are missing or found empty."}

Comment: sorry I don't think anyone else can help you with this. see if reading other threads help: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+oauth